# Sustituir NaN de algunas columnas de un dataFrame

Tags: dataframe

Ocupo sustituir los NaN por el siguiente texto "no registrado" en las columnas de Computer_OS y Mobile_OS. He intentado lo siguiente:

1. dftotal.fillna({"Computer_OS":"no registrado", "Computer_OS_version":"no registrado"}, inplace=True)
2. dftotal.loc[pd.isna(dftotal["Computer_OS"]), "Computer_OS"] = "no registrado"
3. dftotal.loc[:,['Computer_OS','Computer_OS_version']].fillna("no registrado", inplace=True)

y en todas marca error.

La columna Computer_OS tiene tipo de dato object.

¿Qué parte estoy haciendo mal o algo que no esté considerando?

[image: Parte del DataFrame utilizado]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.